# Azure Databricks dbfs with python

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, mount-point

In azure databricks i have different results for the directory list of dbfs by simply adding two dots.
Can anybody explain to me why this happens?

[image: case one]

[image: case two]

Answer (score 2):

With dbutils, you can only use "dbfs:/" paths.
If you do not specify "dbfs:/" at the start of your path, it will simply auto-add it.

```
dbutils.fs.ls('pathA')
--> dbfs:/pathA
```

is exactly the same as

```
dbutils.fs.ls('dbfs:/pathA')
```

but if you do not use the ':', then it will add it silently.

```
dbutils.fs.ls('dbfs/pathB')
--> dbfs:/dbfs/pathB
```

It means your dbfs/ is considered as a folder name **dbfs** at the root of your **dbfs:/**

To avoid confusion, always specify **dbfs:/** to your path.